# Use taylor expansion to study graph geometrically

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have a line which increases very very quick and then decreases very slowly. The graph is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lupNX.png)

And let's assume the maximum occurs when $x=20$. I want to use taylor expansion to claim why in the left of 200, it increases very quickly. So I do this,
$y(x)=y(20)+y^{'}(20)(x-20)+\frac{1}{2}y^{''}(20)(x-20)^2+R$. So if I take x=18 and x=22, both $x-20$ are same and $y(x)$ becomes $y(x)=y(20)+R$, as R is bery small so $y(18)$ and $y(22)$ are really close? But I expect $y(18)$ are much smaller than $y(22)$. So what's wrong here? If I want to use some functions to capture the function's behavior around 20, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

$R$ is *not* necessarily "very small" when you move slightly away from $20$ -- and here, you are at distance $2$. The higher derivatives can (and here, **will**!) play a huge role...

Consider for instance $e^{-(x-20)^3}$. Sure, [the Taylor expansion to order $2$ at $x=20$](http://goo.gl/CqDscn) will give you $1+o((x-20)^2)$, so by your argument above the plot is very "flat" around $x=20$... and [it is, *locally*](http://goo.gl/BctMm8).

[image]

But the terms afterwards increase quite fast: in one case (on the right), they will cancel, so that the function stays "flat"; on the left side, they will add up, so that the function increases very quickly. All that as soon as you go "a little bit too far" from $20$.

[image]

For reference, and to get a better sense of what is going on: the Taylor expansion around $20$ up to higher orders:
$$e^{-(x-20)^3} = 1-(x-20)^3+\frac{1}{2} (x-20)^6-\frac{1}{6} (x-20)^9+o((x-20)^{10})$$
Clearly, the higher-order terms quickly become impossible to neglect when $x$ deviates even a little from $20$...